# How to add categories to your chord diagram in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg, data-visualization

This is my chord diagram with d3.js version 4 (based on [this chart](https://bl.ocks.org/nbremer/d2720fdaab1123df73f4806360a09c9e) in v3) with two added "super categories" (i.e., the the yellow and grey overarching categories) via *Photoshop*:

[image]

You can run the code here:

```js
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //////////////////////// Set-Up ////////////////////////////
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  var margin = {left:90, top:90, right:90, bottom:90},
      width =  1000 - margin.left - margin.right, // more flexibility: Math.min(window.innerWidth, 1000)
      height =  1000 - margin.top - margin.bottom, // same: Math.min(window.innerWidth, 1000)
      innerRadius = Math.min(width, height) * .39,
      outerRadius = innerRadius * 1.1;

    var names = ["Test1","Test2","AMO-DB","YouTube","Twitter", "Google+", "Pflegeratgeber" ,"O-Mag","RuV"],
      colors = ["#301E1E", "#083E77", "#342350", "#567235", "#8B161C", "#DF7C00"],
      opacityDefault = 0.8;

    var matrix = [
      [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], //Test1
      [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1], //Test2
      [0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1], //Hawkeye
      [0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1], //The Hulk
      [0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1], //Iron Man
      [0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1],
      [0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1], //Iron Man
      [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1],
      [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0] //Thor //Thor
    ];

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /////////// Create scale and layout functions //////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    var colors = d3.scaleOrdinal()
        .domain(d3.range(names.length))
      .range(colors);

    var chord = d3.chord()
      .padAngle(.15)
      .sortChords(d3.descending)

      var arc = d3.arc()
      .innerRadius(innerRadius*1.01)
      .outerRadius(outerRadius);

    var path = d3.ribbon()
    .radius(innerRadius);

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  ////////////////////// Create SVG //////////////////////////
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width/2 + margin.left) + "," + (height/2 + margin.top) + ")")
    .datum(chord(matrix));

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  ////////////////// Draw outer Arcs /////////////////////////
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  var outerArcs = svg.selectAll("g.group")
    .data(function(chords) { return chords.groups; })
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "group")
    .on("mouseover", fade(.1))
    .on("mouseout", fade(opacityDefault))

    // text popups
    .on("click", mouseoverChord)
    .on("mouseout", mouseoutChord);


  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  ////////////////////// Append names ////////////////////////
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  //Append the label names INSIDE outside
  outerArcs.append("path")
    .style("fill", function(d) { return colors(d.index); })
    .attr("id", function(d, i) { return "group" + d.index; })
    .attr("d", arc);

   outerArcs.append("text")
           .attr("x", 6)
           .attr("dx", 60)
          .attr("dy", 18)
        .append("textPath")
          .attr("href", function(d) { return "#group" + d.index;})
          .text(function(chords, i){return names[i];})
          .style("fill", "white");

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  ////////////////// Draw inner chords ///////////////////////
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  svg.selectAll("path.chord")
    .data(function(chords) { return chords; })
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "chord")
    .style("fill", function(d) { return colors(d.source.index); })
    .style("opacity", opacityDefault)
    .attr("d", path);

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  ////////////////// Extra Functions /////////////////////////
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  function popup() {
    return function(d,i) {
      console.log("love");
    };
  }//popup

  //Returns an event handler for fading a given chord group.
  function fade(opacity) {
    return function(d,i) {
      svg.selectAll("path.chord")
          .filter(function(d) { return d.source.index != i && d.target.index != i; })
      .transition()
          .style("opacity", opacity);
    };
  }//fade

    //Highlight hovered over chord
  function mouseoverChord(d,i) {

    //Decrease opacity to all
    svg.selectAll("path.chord")
      .transition()
      .style("opacity", 0.1);
    //Show hovered over chord with full opacity
    d3.select(this)
      .transition()
          .style("opacity", 1);

    //Define and show the tooltip over the mouse location
    $(this).popover({
      //placement: 'auto top',
      title: 'test',
      placement: 'right',
      container: 'body',
      animation: false,
      offset: "20px -100px",
      followMouse: true,
      trigger: 'click',
      html : true,
      content: function() {
        return "<p style='font-size: 11px; text-align: center;'><span style='font-weight:900'>"  +
             "</span> text <span style='font-weight:900'>"  +
             "</span> folgt hier <span style='font-weight:900'>" + "</span> movies </p>"; }
    });
    $(this).popover('show');
  }
  //Bring all chords back to default opacity
  function mouseoutChord(d) {
    //Hide the tooltip
    $('.popover').each(function() {
      $(this).remove();
    })
    //Set opacity back to default for all
    svg.selectAll("path.chord")
      .transition()
      .style("opacity", opacityDefault);
    }      //function mouseoutChord
```

```css
 body {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  fill: #2B2B2B;
  cursor: default;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  #chart{
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Chord Diagram</title>

    <!-- D3.js -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- bootstrap 4(!) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id = "chart"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I don’t think, there’s a function in D3.js for "overarching categories" out of the box. I can’t wrap my head around how to implement that. For starters, I thought to define an array where groups are defined and the **sub**groups are included. Then, they are somehow passed to D3.js?

```
// not all arcs in a group must be categorised in super groups.
var groups = [ ["group_name1", "RuV","Test1"], ["group_name2", "Twitter","Google+", "Pflegeratgeber"] ]
```

**Bonus**: I can choose the colours of the super groups.

Comment: Can you not just draw another arc above the categories arcs?

Comment: I wish I knew how. Not good in drawing with svg.

Comment: any update on this?